# SQL - How to count the number of empty and non-empty columns per record?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table that contains 4 columns and I want to create two new columns that count respectively

- the number of non-empty (Count_1) and
- the number of blanks/empty (Count_2)

in the first 4 columns.

In other words, this is my input:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
   X    |    X    |    .    |    Y    
   .    |    .    |    Y    |    X    
   .    |    .    |    .    |    .
```

and this is the desired output:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Count_1 | Count_2
   X    |    X    |    .    |    Y    |    3    |    1        
   .    |    .    |    Y    |    X    |    2    |    2    
   .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    0    |    4
```

Is there any simple solution to this that allows to obtain this output in a single step?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when column1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column4 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as count_1,
       ((case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column2 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column3 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column4 is null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as count_2
from t;
```